# Marker to show current page in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am working on a solution to assist user navigation on a site. Currently, I have a breadcrumb navigation bar underneath my navigation bar showing the full path to the current section of the site that the user is at.

I now want to create a script or use CSS rules to display a marker underneath the tabs in my navigation bar to show which section the user is at. Could somebody please advise me on a general method that I might use to achieving this?

Note that I am using a small .png as an arrow marker which I want to display underneath each tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/f7d7K/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.active {
       background:#ccc url(path/to/image/marker.png) center bottom no-repeat; 
}
```

By switching the marker to clicked link you need to use scripting language like jQuery/Javascript

**jQuery Solution:**

```
$("ul li a").on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
});​
```

Comment: I like it. I like it a lot actually! I am already using jQuery on this project so a jQuery solution is exactly what I needed. Thank you, sir.

Comment: lol. And why would I deprive you of your well-earned points? :D

Comment: I am still a HTML, CSS, Javascript, C# noob. It is people like you that I have to thank for helping me improve as a programmer. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: You are welcome anytime.. By the way yy all learning is due stack overflow community, and I am also thankful to stack overflow community.

Comment: Don't know why this is not getting enough visibility since this is a very common task to solve. Very good answer.

Comment: It gives me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"